# When is CollectionViewSource.Filter event raised in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have some experience of using CollectionViewSource, and can implement sorting, grouping, and filtering  with MVVM pattern. But I am curious when is CollectionViewSource.Filter event raised. My usual way is like  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx), but **this is only registering the event, unlike Button.Click I don't see any where to raise this event, such as by keyboard or mouse**.
So could anyone explain it? Thanks!

Comment: It will be raised each time when the `Source` will changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It will be called whenever the collection changes.
2. You can reevaluate the filter manually if your filter's criteria changes by calling `ICollectionView.Refresh` in your view model code:

   ```
   collectionViewSource.View.Refresh();
   ```
3. You can prevent calling the filter repeatedly when you're doing batch modifications:

   ```
   using (collectionViewSource.DeferRefresh())
   {
       // update your collection in here
   }
   ```